# Not able to create repository in spring roo

Tags: spring, spring-roo

After painful installation of spring roo . I am trying to create a project . 
However after making a pojo via spring shell i am now creating the spring repository .
I ran the following commands for creating the POJO

```
entity jpa --class ~.DTO.UserDTO
field string --fieldName name --notNull --sizeMin 50
```

So far so good but here's where trouble comes :

```
 repository jpa --entity ~.DTO.UserDTO --interface ~.repository.UserDTORepository
```

Immediately i get this message 
--entity option should be an entity.
I am badly stuck .
I tried deleting the pojo and ran tyhe following commands :

```
entity jpa --class ~.DTO.UserDTO --testAutomatically --activeRecord false
```

Message that i got was :
`"Options 'testAutomatically', 'activeRecord' are not available for this command. Use tab assist or the "help" command to see the legal options`"
And i tried 
`"repository jpa --entity ~.dto.UserRecord --interface ~.repository.UserRepository`"
Got the message

```
--entity option should be an entity.
This is where i gave up
```

My Environment is java 1.8 , spring roo 2.0.0.RC1 
STS 3.9.0.Release .

Answer (score 2):

I've been checking your issue, and if you write `repository jpa --entity` in the Spring Roo shell and after that you press the autocompletion key (`TAB` or `CTRL + Space`), you will see that the following result appear: `~.dto.UserDTO`.

So use

`repository jpa --entity ~.dto.UserDTO --interface ~.repository.UserDTORepository`

instead of

`repository jpa --entity ~.DTO.UserDTO --interface ~.repository.UserDTORepository`

See that the difference is in the capital letters of `~.DTO` package. When you entered the name of your entity, you used `~.DTO` as name of the package, but Spring Roo changes all to lower case. The reason is that, as you could check in the [Oracle Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/namingpkgs.html) the package names are written in all lower case to avoid conflict with the names of classes or interfaces.

Remember that is really important that you use the `TAB` or `CTRL + Space` to construct the command that you will execute to prevent this kind of errors.

Hope it helps,